# Compare two DataTables rows by specific identifier and marking them accordingly

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, comparison, datarow

I have two exactly same DataTables ("Old" and "New") and I want to compare rows with same identifier.

For example both datatables (dt1 , dt2) have "ID" column and so I want to compare row from dt1 where "ID = 1" to same row in dt2 (Where ID = 1) and see if any cell is different in dt2 for that row .

```
dt1 (Old)                   |        dt2 (New)
____                             ________
ID , Col1 , Col2            |   ID , Col1 , Col2 

1 ,"somedata","somedata2"   |  1 ,"somedata","somedata2"    -> Same
5 ,"somedata","somedata2"   |  5 ,"somedata","somedata2"    -> Same
90 ,"somedata","somedata2"  |  90 ,"changed","somedata2"   -> Changed
100 ,"somedata","somedata2" |  100 ,"somedata","changed"  -> Changed
```

So I want to info write a function which will return List of ID's which has changed (90,100) for this example.

Would appreciate any help .

I am coding on C# so would love if anyone knows how to solve this problem using Linq.

Comment: Declare a primary key for one of the tables, then enumerate the other, `Find`ing in the first table by the PK value of the second table row, then compare the values in each row's itemarray

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
The function I would use would be a bit like this:

```
public List<int> DatableCompare(DataTable oldDt, DataTable newDt)
{
    var changedIds = new List<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i < oldDt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         if (!oldDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.SequenceEqual(newDt.Rows[i].ItemArray))
         {
             changedIds.Add((int)oldDt.Rows[i][0]);
         }
    }
    return changedIds;
}
```

Hope this helped!

This is assuming your Datatable's first column is of type int, it will crash otherwise.. maybe a [Convert.ToInt32()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-6.0) of some sort would be safer

Comment: Yes , it looks good but I have many more columns to compare . Thanks

Comment: @JmukhadzeT I edited my answer, I thought of a nice way to compare the whole array of elements